# When do cookies+static files become a relevant issue?

Tags: performance, http, optimization, http-headers, nginx

I've recently read an article http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/ about *Serving Static Content from a Cookieless Domain*. The question I have is – **how many request does the server need to handle in order for this to become a relevant issue?**

- At the moment all content is served from dev.[domain].
- I am thinking to setup subdomain static.[domain] ([domain] itself doesn't set any cookies).
- My server is handling approx. 5 000 static file requests every minute.

Comment: 5000 req/min is less than 100 req/sec, so I would not bother. But then, I never managed a server with so many hits.

Comment: My question is asking *when* is it time, not whether 5 000 is the benchmark. Is it 10 000, 25 000, more?

Comment: Then your question is a web server administration issue, so off-topic here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, you might be right. Please move the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of the mentioned article. I think RickNZ's answer is good but I wanted to point out that there are two different types of performance at hand. One is a question about server load and bandwidth -- which it seems OP is concerned with -- and the other is about page performance.

For the former I think it's just a matter of doing the math to see if the cookies account for a significant portion of bandwidth.

For the latter it's mostly about the number of static requests per page. Relative to the page payload, even large cookies are pretty small. If the cookie is 500 bytes and your page has only 10 static assets, we're only talking about 5K. But if you have 200 static assets, now the bloat is 100K, which can be a significant amount of weight.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to cookies, the decision about whether to serve static files from a separate domain should be driven initially more by the size of your cookies than the number of requests.

If your cookies are large (more than a few tens of bytes), and especially if you have many static files per page, then clients will experience a performance penalty as they upload the cookies with every request.

There are other reasons to use a different domain for static files -- it can help improve page load times for older browsers, such as IE7.

If you're looking for a more concrete heuristic, how about this:

```
if ((the size of cookies attached to static files > 50 bytes) ||
    (your web logs show > 10% accesses from IE7 or older) ||
    (more than 20% of your pages request > 10 static files))
then
    use one or more subdomains for your static files
```

An alternative to using a separate domain is to attach a "path" attribute to your cookies, so that they aren't assigned to your static content. For example, put all of your dynamic content in a folder called `/pages`, and have your static content in a folder called `/static`. Then set `path=/pages` on your cookies, and your static files won't have cookies.

Comment: I shouldn't really worry about it if my cookie is barely 209 characters long?

Comment: Well 209 is more than 50... The impact depends in part on how many static files you have per page. If there are 9, then the browser is uploading (9+1)*209 = 2090 bytes per page request (one extra for the page itself). For 100 req/sec, that's 20900 bytes/sec (appx 200Kbps) just for cookies.

Comment: Well, that doesn't sound a lot. Either way, this answer gives me general idea of what it's all about.